# iOS BLE: `discoverServices: nil` sometimes only discovers one service

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm using

```
[central connectPeripheral: peripheral options: nil];
```

and

```
NSData *data1 = [NSData dataWithBytes:serialPortServiceUuid length:SERIAL_PORT_SERVICE_UUID_LEN];
CBUUID *uuid1 = [CBUUID UUIDWithData:data1];

NSData *data2 = [NSData dataWithBytes:deviceIdServiceUuid length:SERVICE_UUID_DEFAULT_LEN];
CBUUID *uuid2 = [CBUUID UUIDWithData:data2];

[peripheral discoverServices:@[uuid1, uuid2]];
```

which sometimes finds both services of my peripheral, sometimes only one (`UUID = Device Information`). It seems to me as if it's more reliable if there's some time between connection attempts and fails more often if it should reconnect automatically (I'm doing a `connect` in the `disconnect`).

What irritates me is that the connection seems to be established and that services are found, but only one and not both of them (I'm looking for services with the IDs, not `nil`).

Any ideas?

*EDIT*

My peripheral is a custom made medical product, everything works as expected when the connection is setup "manually", not via reestablishing.

So what works is pressing a button and then do the `connectPeripheral` => `discoverServices` thing, what does NOT work is do a `connectPeripheral` in my `didDisconnect` method; `didDiscoverServices` is called as well, but only with one instead of two services.

Comment: I'm a little confused; your question is tagged Swift, but you have shown Objective-C. You are asking about service discovery but shown code that connects.  Can you show the service retrieval code?   What is your peripheral?

Comment: sorry, I edited my question. Regarding Objective-C/Swift: the BLE part is still written in Objective-C, but the app gets more and more converted to Swift, therefore the tag, but I removed it, my fault...